# Routes not working as desired in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to build a full stack application with User login/logout functionality.

I want to protect certain pages such that they can only be viewed when the user is logged in. For login I have created a REST API and I am using session storage to keep track of whether the user is logged in or not.

```
validateUser = () => {

        let user = { 

            username: this.state.email, 
            password: this.state.password,
            //status: "LOGGED_IN"
        };
        
        UserService.authenticateUser(user).then((res) => {
            if(res.data === 'SUCCESS') {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem("isUserLogged", true);

      
            } else if(res.data === 'FAILURE') {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem("isUserLogged", false);
                this.resetLoginForm();
                this.setState({"error":"Invalid username or password"});
            }
        })
    };
```

Tis is my App.js

```
function App() {


  return (

    <div>
      <Router>
          <HeaderComponent/>
          <div className="container">
            <Switch> 
              <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPageComponent}></Route>
              {/* <Route path ="/customers" component = {ListCustomerComponent}></Route> */}
              {/* <Route path ="/add-customer/:id" component = {CreateCustomerComponent}></Route> */}
              <Route path = "/view-customer/:id" component = {ViewCustomerComponent}></Route>
              <Route path = "/admin-login" component = {AdminLoginComponent}></Route>
              <Route path = "/admin-register" component = {AdminResgisterComponent}></Route>

              <Route path="/customers" exact render={() => (
                window.sessionStorage.getItem("isUserLogged") === "true"
                ? <ListCustomerComponent />
                : <Redirect to='/admin-login' />
              )} />

              <Route path="/add-customer/:id" exact render={() => (
                window.sessionStorage.getItem("isUserLogged") === "true"
                ? <CreateCustomerComponent />
                : <Redirect to='/admin-login' />
              )} />

              
            </Switch>
          </div>
          <FooterComponent/>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
} 

export default App;
```

Everything works fine if I don't check my session storage. But when I try to implement the conditional routes as shown above I start getting errors.

[image: Error]

If I just put simple routes, then I don't encounter this error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass Route props into your component. So `history` does not included in `props`, you can `console.log(this.props)` to check what `this.props` contains.

To fix it, let's pass `Route` props into your components

```
<Route path="/add-customer/:id" exact render={(props) => (
   window.sessionStorage.getItem("isUserLogged") === "true"
   ? <CreateCustomerComponent {...props} /> // ADD PROPS HERE
   : <Redirect to='/admin-login' />
} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what you did on `ListCustomerComponent`.
You could try to encapsulate your component using HOC `withRouter` or if you are using Functional component, use `useHistory` hook.

```js
// on export class component

export default withRouter(YourComponent)
```

in functional component, you can use

```js
const YourComponent = ()=>{
  
  const history = useHistory();
  // then you can say something such as
  // history.push(...)

  return <>...your view here...</>
}


export default YourComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Switch>
    {/* Login Sections goes Here */}
    <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage} />
    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
    <Route exact path='/admin/' component={LoginAdmin} />
    <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />

    {/* AdminUser ROutes goes here */}
    <SuperUserDashboard>
      <Route exact path='/admin/dashboard' component={Dashboardpage} />
      <Route exact path='/admin/users' component={UsersAdmin} />
    </SuperUserDashboard>

    <Route exact path='' component={Notfound} />
  </Switch>
```

in superuser dashboard check if user is authenticated if not redirect to admin login page else all the routes will be visible